# Проблема отправки архива в AppStore

Tags: xcode, profile

Всем привет! У меня есть проект, собранный в Unity. Я пытаюсь его загрузить в AppStore. Я сделал все необходимое: создал профайл, сертификат и идентификатор на сайте "developer.apple.com". Указываю эти же данные в xCode и в AppStorе. Сам архив собирается в xCode, но при попытке отправить его в AppStore, мне говорит, что неверный Bundle ID, хотя проверил тысячу раз, что всё везде указано верно. В чем может быть проблема?
Скрины прикрепил.

[image: ошибка в иксКоде]
[image: перед сборкой архива]
[image: перед отправкой архива в апстор]
[image: Bundle ID в АпСтор приложения]
[image: настройки профайла]

Comment: Вроде как мне помогло когдато добавить к бандл название группы разработчиков, в начале, также через точку

Comment: А вы пробовали автоматическую подпись?

Comment: пробовал добавить название команды в начало бандла, выкинуло ошибку сразу перед сборкой архива, что не найден такой бандл. с автоматической подписью такая же ошибка :(

Comment: аккаунт оплачен и тд?

Comment: да, все оплачено со стороны apple, разве что юнити бесплатная, но это вроде не имеет значения

Comment: это все очень странно, на сайте написано что ожидает загрузки(желтый кружок)

Comment: а в юнити нужно профайлы указывать?

Comment: врядли, конкретно unity приложения не заливал. Советую написать apple support